# Cannot figure out why button is not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button to submit answers to go on to the next question on my quiz app.
However when I try to put it in the div where my quiz is at the button disappears.
What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Here is my code:

```js
var quizApp = Quiz(questions, $('#quiz-area'));
  
quizApp.questionDisplay(); // currentQuestion = 0, valid question
  
$('#next').on('click', quizApp.nextQuestion);
$('#totalQuestions').text(questions.length);
  
// TODO: Add event listener for reset
$('#reset').on('click', quizApp.reset);
```

```css
#quiz-area{
margin: 150px 160px;
padding: 100px 40px 40px 40px;
width: 500px;
height: 400px;
background-image: url("http://hardwoodhustle.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/HWH-BG1.jpg");  
background-repeat: no-repeat;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-mox-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}

div #quiz-area{
border: red 1px solid;
}

#quiz-area ul {
border: 1px solid red;
}

#quiz-area li,
#quiz-area ul {
list-style-type: none;
padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="quiz-area">
<div id="next">    
 <button id="next" type="submit">Submit Answer</button>
 <div id="score"><span id="correct">0</span>/<span id="totalQuestions">20</span></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you include all your relevant code?

Comment: Your button is there (??).

Comment: Your button and div have the same id. This is not allowed in html. Not sure if this is your problem, but it is A problem.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what the `quizApp.nextQuestion` function does, but if it replaces the contents of `#quiz-area` that would remove the event listener within the contents.

Comment: Are you using a wordpress plugin? If so difficult to guess which one. See @Lenny 's comments for HTML errors.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. My logic I used creates the HTML for my questions in my app and it wiped out my button. Here is how I fixed it:

```
<div id="quiz-container">    
    <div id="quiz-area"></div>
    <div id="score">
        <span><button id="next" type="submit">Submit Answer</button></span>
        <span id="score-board"><span id="correct">0</span>/<span id="totalQuestions">20</span></span>
    </div>
</div>
```